# Extract meta description from web pages using R

Tags: r, rvest, httr

Hi i am trying to retrive these wepages meta descriptions

from the pages sources "

```
Data<-data.frame(Pages=c(
"http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/spam-king-sanford-wallace.html", 
"http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/omg-the-japanese-trump-commer.html",
"http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/omar-mateen-posted-to-facebook.html"))
```

Desired output

```
Data$Meta_Description<-data.frame(Extracted=c(
"Sanford Wallace gets 2.5 years in prison for 27 million Facebook", 
"OMG, this Japanese Trump Commercial is everything",
"Omar Mateen posted to Facebook during Orlando mass shooting"))
```

I was trying to achieved this task with httr but I am not ablet to get it in the desired ouput format or extract content from what it is retrieved using the GET command

```
library (httr)
resp<-GET ("http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/spam-king-sanford-wallace.html")
str(resp)
List of 10
$ url        : chr "http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/spam-king-sanford-wallace.html"
$ status_code: int 200
$ headers    :List of 22
..$ server                     : chr "Apache/2.2"
```

The field that i need to extract from the source code is after this string

```
<meta itemprop="description" content="
```

Like so

```
<meta itemprop="description" content="&#039;Spam King&#039; 
Sanford Wallace gets 2.5 years in prison for 27 million Facebook scam messages"
```

Comment: What output do you currently have?

Comment: resp <- GET ("http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/spam-king-sanford-wallace.html") the output is a list 
str(resp)
List of 10

Comment: What is in this list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really only need `rvest`. Since they're all `<h1>` headings, you can just iterate over the list of URLs, picking out the headings:

```
library(rvest)

sapply(Data$Pages, 
       function(url){
           url %>% 
               as.character() %>%   # in case strings are stored as factors
               read_html() %>% 
               html_nodes('h1') %>% 
               html_text()
           })

# [1] "'Spam King' Sanford Wallace gets 2.5 years in prison for 27 million Facebook scam messages"
# [2] "OMG, this Japanese Trump Commercial is everything"                                         
# [3] "Omar Mateen posted to Facebook during Orlando mass shooting"
```

Or if you *really* want to scrape the `<meta>` tags, you can do it in the same way, though the selectors are more of a pain:

```
sapply(Data$Pages, function(url){
    url %>% 
        as.character() %>% 
        read_html() %>% 
        html_nodes(xpath = '//meta[@itemprop="description"]') %>% 
        html_attr('content')
    })
```

You get the same results either way.